# How to create SQL table with columns from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, dbeaver

I have three tables in MySQL 'Customers', 'Deliverys_History'. The 'Customers' table has the customer ID and name information, while the 'Deliverys_History' table has the relationship of the orders placed by a customer, the status change date and the status_id.

I need to create an auxiliary table (for later export) that has the customer id, name, and order arrival date vs order ship date to make a minute differentiation between them.

Customers table

| CustomerID | CustomerName |
| --- | --- |
| 000001 | Pepe |
| 000002 | John |
| 000003 | Adi |
| 000004 | Louis |

History table

| Timestamp | StatusID | CustomerID | ArticleID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-15 16:40:00 | 11 | 000001 | 520369 |
| 2022-12-15 18:42:24 | 11 | 000002 | 520370 |
| 2022-12-15 20:44:48 | 11 | 000003 | 520371 |
| 2022-12-15 22:47:12 | 12 | 000001 | 520372 |
| 2022-12-16 00:49:36 | 11 | 000003 | 520373 |
| 2022-12-16 02:52:00 | 11 | 000001 | 520374 |
| 2022-12-16 04:54:24 | 11 | 000004 | 520375 |
| 2022-12-16 06:56:48 | 12 | 000001 | 520376 |
| 2022-12-16 16:40:00 | 12 | 000002 | 520377 |
| 2022-12-16 18:42:24 | 12 | 000003 | 520378 |
| 2022-12-16 20:44:48 | 12 | 000003 | 520379 |
| 2022-12-16 22:47:12 | 12 | 000004 | 520380 |
| 2022-12-17 00:49:36 | 11 | 000001 | 520381 |
| 2022-12-17 02:52:00 | 12 | 000001 | 520382 |

Output

| CustomerID | CustomerName | Lap | Arrive(11) | Dispatch(12) | Diff (min) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | Pepe | 1 | 2022-12-15 16:40:00 | 2022-12-15 18:42:24 | 122 |
| 000001 | Pepe | 2 | 2022-12-16 02:52:00 | 2022-12-16 06:56:48 | 245 |
| 000001 | Pepe | 3 | 2022-12-17 00:49:36 | 2022-12-17 02:52:00 | 122 |
| 000002 | John | 1 | 2022-12-15 18:42:24 | 2022-12-16 16:40:00 | 1318 |
| 000003 | Adi | 1 | 2022-12-15 20:44:48 | 2022-12-16 18:42:24 | 1318 |
| 000003 | Adi | 2 | 2022-12-16 00:49:36 | 2022-12-16 20:44:48 | 1195 |

The lap column must be the key to extract de dates relationship.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi - How do we tell which records for the same customer refer to the same order? As this is not a free code writing service, please update your question with the SQL you’ve managed to write on your own and ask a specific question about an issue you are facing

Comment: Your addition of `ArticleID` appears to be just a surrogate key. Where is the OrderID relationship? What relates a StatusID 11 row to a StatusID 12 row?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the OrderID, so there is no reliable way of linking status changes for an order. The following uses an intermediate cte to apply a *"made up"* order number:

```sql
WITH Deliveries_History (Timestamp, StatusID, CustomerID, OrderID) AS (
    SELECT Timestamp, StatusID, CustomerID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID, StatusID ORDER BY Timestamp)
    FROM Deliverys_History
)
SELECT
    a.CustomerID,
    c.CustomerName,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.CustomerID ORDER BY a.Timestamp) AS Lap,
    a.Timestamp AS Arrive,
    d.Timestamp AS Dispatch,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, a.Timestamp, d.Timestamp) AS Diff
FROM Deliveries_History a
JOIN Deliveries_History d
    ON a.CustomerID = d.CustomerID
    AND a.OrderID = d.OrderID
    AND d.StatusID = 12
JOIN Customers c
    ON a.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
WHERE a.StatusID = 11
ORDER BY a.CustomerID, a.Timestamp;
```

This should not be replied upon due to the *"made up"* `OrderID`!